# System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I try to get the summary for items in a specific place. I try to group them becasuse one item can be multiple times in the specific place and get summary for that item.It works fine with ITEMID and REMAIN but it fails when i try to access Description
My command looks like this

```cs
var items1 = await _context.Set<Comitemtran>()
    .Include(c => c.Bzitem)?
    .Include(c => c.Bzchopp)?
    .Include(c => c.Bzitemlot)?
    .Include(c => c.Bzstoreplace)?
    .Where(c => c.Bzstoreplaceid == placecode).GroupBy(c => c.Bzitemid).Select(group => new ItemTransView
    {
        BZITEMID = group.Key,
        BZDESC = group.Where(c => c.Bzitemid == group.Key).FirstOrDefault().Bzitem.Bzdesc,


        BZREMAIN = group.Sum(s => s.Bzquantity)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

When i execute it i get this response on postman:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: c.BZITEMID,
> ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: Comitemtran
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False .Select(s => s.Bzitem.Bzdesc) .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Description` to grouping key. In this case query will be translated to the SQL

```cs
var items1 = await _context.Set<Comitemtran>()
    .Where(c => c.Bzstoreplaceid == placecode)
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.Bzitemid, c.Bzitem.Bzdesc })
    .Select(group => new ItemTransView
    {
        BZITEMID = group.Key.Bzitemid,
        BZDESC = group.Key.Bzdesc,
        BZREMAIN = group.Sum(s => s.Bzquantity)
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Note that `Include`'s are ignored when followed by `Select`.

Comment: Still get the same error on postman in debugger looks fine.Thanks for your answer

Comment: I do not get this comment. It works or not?

Comment: Forget about it silly mistake by me it works perfect thanks a lot!!!Save my day!!!!